# CarrierWave Multiple file Upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to upload multiple files using carrier wave. Whenever I am trying to upload the file, I am able to upload the only single file. Even I have added the array of hash in permit({image: []}) under the floorplan controller.

It is the controller.

```
class FloorplansController < ApplicationController

def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @floorplan  = Floorplan.create(params[:floorplan].permit(:name,{image: []}))
    @floorplan.user_id = current_user.id
    @floorplan.project_id = @project.id

    if @floorplan.save
        redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

end

It is the form partial from where I am uploading the files.

```
= simple_form_for([@project, @project.floorplans.build],input_html: {multiple: true }) do |f|
= f.input :name, label: "Name the Floorplan"
= f.input :image, input_html: {multiple: true }, name:"floorplan[image][]", label: "Attach the Floorplan Image"
= f.button :submit, class: "button"
```

After that, I attached jquery file uploader as explained in RailsCast episode 381 
floorplan.coffee
`jQuery ->
    $('#new_floorplan').fileupload()`

And these are my db migrations

```
class AddImageToFloorplans < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
   def change
     add_column :floorplans, :image, :string
   end
end
```

Comment: You can put a byebug at beginning of create action. Just to ensure if you are getting the images array.

Comment: are you using nested attributes for image uploads?

Comment: i think you should use `f.simple_fields_for(floorplans)`

Comment: @gabbar Yes, I am trying to use nested attributes because I found this solution for uploading multiple files. Will f.simple_fields_for in place of ??

Comment: hmm if you dnt mind i can give you simple idea for uploading multiple file.you can get road block by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

1- in Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'nested_form_fields'
```

2- application.js.erb

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require nested_form_fields
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

3- in `new` action

```
def new
  @project = Peoject.new
  @project.@project.floorplans.build
end
```

4.- in view form

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
   <%=f.nested_fields_for :floorplans do |floorplan|%>
     <%=floorplan.remove_nested_fields_link 'Remove'%>
     <%=floorplan.file_field :image%>
   <%end%>
   <%=f.add_nested_fields_link :floorplans, 'Add Photo'%>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

5- in `create` action

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @floorplan.save
        redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, floorplans_attributes: [:image])
end
```

6- for more [reference](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields) you can follow this